# Receive the body content in the HTTP response in python

Tags: python, sockets, http, recv

I am trying to get the content from the body but when I need the sock.recv I always have a return of 0 bytes. I already got the header and it worked fine but I received it byte by byte. my problem now is: I have the content length the length of the header and also the header. Now i want to get the body separately
Task 3d

PS: I am aware that it can't work as it is on the screenshot but I haven't found another solution yet

```
  # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
task3.simple_web_browser
XX-YYY-ZZZ
<Your name>
"""

from socket import gethostbyname, socket, timeout, AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM
from sys import argv


HTTP_HEADER_DELIMITER = b'\r\n\r\n'
CONTENT_LENGTH_FIELD = b'Content-Length:'
HTTP_PORT = 80
ONE_BYTE_LENGTH = 1

def create_http_request(host, path, method='GET'):
    '''
    Create a sequence of bytes representing an HTTP/1.1 request of the given method.

    :param host: the string contains the hostname of the remote server
    :param path: the string contains the path to the document to retrieve
    :param method: the string contains the HTTP request method (e.g., 'GET', 'HEAD', etc...)
    :return: a bytes object contains the HTTP request to send to the remote server

    e.g.,) An HTTP/1.1 GET request to http://compass.unisg.ch/
    host: compass.unisg.ch
    path: /
    return: b'GET / HTTP/1.1\nHost: compass.unisg.ch\r\n\r\n'
    '''
    ###   Task 3(a)   ###

    # Hint 1: see RFC7230-7231 for the HTTP/1.1 syntax and semantics specification
    # https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230
    # https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231
    # Hint 2: use str.encode() to create an encoded version of the string as a bytes object
    # https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode
    r =  '{} {} HTTP/1.1\nHost: {}\r\n\r\n'.format(method, path, host)
    response = r.encode()

    return response


    ### Task 3(a) END ###


def get_content_length(header):
    '''
    Get the integer value from the Content-Length HTTP header field if it
    is found in the given sequence of bytes. Otherwise returns 0.

    :param header: the bytes object contains the HTTP header
    :return: an integer value of the Content-Length, 0 if not found
    '''
    ###   Task 3(c)   ###

    # Hint: use CONTENT_LENGTH_FIELD to find the value
    # Note that the Content-Length field may not be always at the end of the header.
    for line in header.split(b'\r\n'):
        if CONTENT_LENGTH_FIELD in line:
            return int(line[len(CONTENT_LENGTH_FIELD):])
    return 0


    ### Task 3(c) END ###


def receive_body(sock, content_length):
    '''
    Receive the body content in the HTTP response

    :param sock: the TCP socket connected to the remote server
    :param content_length: the size of the content to recieve
    :return: a bytes object contains the remaining content (body) in the HTTP response
    '''
    ###   Task 3(d)   ###
    body = bytes()
    data = bytes()


    while True:
        data = sock.recv(content_length)
        if len(data)<=0:
            break
        else:
            body += data

    return body 


    ### Task 3(d) END ###


def receive_http_response_header(sock):
    '''
    Receive the HTTP response header from the TCP socket.

    :param sock: the TCP socket connected to the remote server
    :return: a bytes object that is the HTTP response header received
    '''
    ###   Task 3(b)   ###

    # Hint 1: use HTTP_HEADER_DELIMITER to determine the end of the HTTP header
    # Hint 2: use sock.recv(ONE_BYTE_LENGTH) to receive the chunk byte-by-byte

    header = bytes() 
    chunk = bytes()

    try:
        while HTTP_HEADER_DELIMITER not in chunk:
            chunk = sock.recv(ONE_BYTE_LENGTH)
            if not chunk:
                break
            else:
                header += chunk
    except socket.timeout:
        pass

    return header  

    ### Task 3(b) END ###


def main():
    # Change the host and path below to test other web sites!
    host = 'example.com'
    path = '/index.html'
    print(f"# Retrieve data from http://{host}{path}")

    # Get the IP address of the host
    ip_address = gethostbyname(host)
    print(f"> Remote server {host} resolved as {ip_address}")

    # Establish the TCP connection to the host
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.connect((ip_address, HTTP_PORT))
    print(f"> TCP Connection to {ip_address}:{HTTP_PORT} established")

 # Uncomment this comment block after Task 3(a)
    # Send an HTTP GET request
    http_get_request = create_http_request(host, path)
    print('\n# HTTP GET request ({} bytes)'.format(len(http_get_request)))
    print(http_get_request)
    sock.sendall(http_get_request)
 # Comment block for Task 3(a) END

 # Uncomment this comment block after Task 3(b)
    # Receive the HTTP response header
    header = receive_http_response_header(sock)
    print(type(header))
    print('\n# HTTP Response Header ({} bytes)'.format(len(header)))
    print(header)
 # Comment block for Task 3(b) END

#  Uncomment this comment block after Task 3(c)
    content_length = get_content_length(header)
    print('\n# Content-Length')
    print(f"{content_length} bytes")
 # Comment block for Task 3(c) END

 # Uncomment this comment block after Task 3(d)
    body = receive_body(sock, content_length)
    print('\n# Body ({} bytes)'.format(len(body)))
    print(body)
 # Comment block for Task 3(d) END

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: If its http request, why cant you use python `requests` package? Its very simple to use, like `requests.get("http://example.com").content`

Comment: in this exercise you are not allowed to use the requests library...

Comment: @Chris thanks for the tip I have never used stackoverflow before

Comment: *"I have the content length the length of the header and also the header."* - do you? In `receive_http_response_header` you check `HTTP_HEADER_DELIMITER` always only again the latest byte  (`chunk` instead of `header`) which means that you'll never match the end of the header.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Yes I found the mistake before. Thank You anyway..

Comment: @SteffenUllrich The only problem I couldn`t solve yet is the exception handling of 3.d I have now the right output but it does not work with pytest because other exception then socket.timeout occure.

Comment: @LorisMayr: I have no idea what you are currently doing. As can be seen from my answer the code you show for `receive_body` is wrong too, which might also the reason why you get a timeout.

Answer (score 0):

> I have the content length the length of the header and also the header

You don't. In `receive_http_response_header` you check `HTTP_HEADER_DELIMITER` always only again the latest byte  (`chunk` instead of `header`) which means that you'll never match the end of the header:

```
    while HTTP_HEADER_DELIMITER not in chunk:
        chunk = sock.recv(ONE_BYTE_LENGTH)
        if not chunk:
            break
        else:
            header += chunk
```

Then you just assume that you've read the full header while in reality you've read the full response. This means that another `recv` you are doing when trying to read the response body will only return 0 since no more data are there, i.e. the body was already included in what you consider the HTTP header.

Apart from that `receive_body` is wrong too since you make a similar mistake is in `receive_http_response_header`: the goal is not to read `recv` `content_length` bytes again and again until no more bytes are available as you do currently but the goal is to return when `length(body)` matches the `content_length` and continue reading the remaining data as long the body is not fully read.